# PS3 and PS4 switch

Tags: ps3, ps4, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online, psn

If I have PS3 and I have gta online on it and I use same PSN ID on PS4 will I still have same gta online account?

Thank you for answer

Comment: Just the account or do you want to access your progress and characters on the PS4?

Comment: Yes I think it like if I will have all characters, progress and money